# Javascript click not working as desired

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement something like what is pictured below; when Divs looking like buttons are clicked, it would show details about them. I am using inline Javascript as well as an external JavaScript file. My problem is that when I click on the first div, it shows detailed information about it. But when I click the other divs nothing happens.

My HTML code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Crash Test</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="javascript/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Mobile Phones</legend>
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <script language="javascript">
                                var secArray = new Array();
                                secArray = ["Asus","HTC","Apple","Samsung","Nokia"];

                                for(var secCnt=1;secCnt<=secArray.length;secCnt++){
                                    document.write('<div class="allSections currentSectionSelected" id="s">');
                                    document.write('<div href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip tooltipSelected">');
                                    document.write('<div style="text-overflow:ellipsis;width:92%;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap; padding:5px;font-weight: bold;" onclick="javascript:setSecName('+secCnt+',secArray);">');
                                    document.write(secArray[secCnt-1]);
                                    document.write('</div>');
                                    document.write('</div>');
                                    document.write('</div>');
                                }
                            </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                for(var secCnt=1;secCnt<=secArray.length;secCnt++){
                                    if(secCnt == CurrentSection){
                                        document.write('<div id="viewSection'+secCnt+'" style="display:block">You are viewing all about <b>'+secArray[secCnt-1]+'</b> mobile phone: <br><br>');
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        document.write('<div id="viewSection'+secCnt+'" style="display:none;">You are viewing all about <b>'+secArray[secCnt-1]+'</b> mobile phone: <br><br>');
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my external javascript file code is:

```
var CurrentSection =1;

function setSecName(sectioncount,sa){
    CurrentSection=sectioncount;

    load_details(sa);
}

function load_details(sa){
    var secArray =sa;
    for(var secCnt=1;secCnt<=secArray.length;secCnt++){
        if(secCnt == CurrentSection){
            document.getElementById('viewSection'+secCnt).style.display = "block";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('viewSection'+secCnt).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

---

I want to achieve the above functionality using Javascript only.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

[image: ent]

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you left detail information div elements unclosed. Corrected code:

```
for (var secCnt = 1; secCnt <= secArray.length; secCnt++) {
    if (secCnt == CurrentSection) {
        document.write('<div id="viewSection' + secCnt + '" style="display:block">You are viewing all about <b>' + secArray[secCnt - 1] + '</b> mobile phone: <br><br></div>');
    } else {
        document.write('<div id="viewSection' + secCnt + '" style="display:none;">You are viewing all about <b>' + secArray[secCnt - 1] + '</b> mobile phone: <br><br></div>');
    }
}
```

Note that I added `</div>` in above code.

Also `document.write` is not the best way to render and display information. You should probably make use of some static elements or create elements dynamically with `document.createElement` and `appendChild` methods.

Comment: 'dfsq' thank you million times.You saved me from going crazy.How dumb i was, i did not notice the unclosed div.You are great!!!!! :)